# Importing tensorflow causes python to throw errors and runs another script

Tags: python, tensorflow, tkinter, keras

i was working with a simple project with tensorflow and Tkinter, now tensorflow and keras don't work anymore and i'm getting strange errors, and an old deleted code automaticaly runs ?

I deleted the script that keeps running  , and tried to re-install tensorflow but i'm still getting the same errors, here is the stacktrace

```
  import tensorflow as tf

  File "C:\Users\Ce PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\Ce PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import keras
  File "C:\Users\Ce PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import activations
  File "C:\Users\Ce PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\activations\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.activations import elu
  File "C:\Users\Ce PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras import preprocessing
  File "C:\Users\Ce PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\preprocessing\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.preprocessing import image
  File "C:\Users\Ce PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 45, in <module>
    import scipy.ndimage as ndi
  File "C:\Users\Ce PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\ndimage\__init__.py", line 161, in <module>
    from .filters import *
  File "C:\Users\Ce PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\ndimage\filters.py", line 37, in <module>
    from scipy.misc import doccer
  File "C:\Users\Ce PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    from .pilutil import *
  File "C:\Users\Ce PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\pilutil.py", line 26, in <module>
    Image.frombytes = Image.fromstring
AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'fromstring'
```

Comment: maybe you have own file with path `PIL/Image.py` and now Python tries to use it instead of module `PIL` . You may check path `import PIL ; print(PIL.__file__)` and `from PIL import Image ; print(Image.__file__)`

Comment: that fixed my problem , thanks !